# Kubuntu stop recognizing audio input devices

Tags: microphone

I installed Kubuntu 20.04. My microphone worked well. But recently, I have tried droidcam (I'm regretting so much), and my laptop microphone stopped working.

It doesn't recognize any input device on it.

This is the result for `arecord -l`

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu!   Have you tried to install pavucontrol? `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` also, make sure it is "on" and not "muted" in the volume settings (applications and advanced)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing a lot of answers, I solved it just by removing configuration files:

rm .config/pulse/*

Then I run

pulseaudio -k

And restarted

Everything is ok now